# How can I prevent graph truncation in Graphite URL API?

Tags: graphite

I have some graphs in graphite which sometimes render with their top chopped off, see example below. How can I prevent this? The yMax parameter does not work for me because I don't know a max ahead of time.

[image: Graphite Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had encountered the same problem and found that even setting explicit yMax cannot work-around it (unless larger enough to cross the next "step").

Had come up with a fix quickly, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/graphite/+bug/1007480/comments/4.